# Angular 8 (Typescript) Key value pair input fields output modification

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, key-value

Hello Team I need to create two input fields in angular that forms a key value pair exactly like the below image, I have found a article that does the same but the output result from this fields input is not in expected format which I want.

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:-

`{ "details": [ { "select1-inputvalue": "select2-inputvalue" }, { "select1-inputvalue": "select2-inputvalue" } ] }`

The article I found uses reactive forms to achieve this, I have tried different approach to create the output as the expected Json object but it did not work, as I am not a angular expert a help is appreciated. Also the existing fork contains a text input for me it will be a dropdown.

**Existing Post:**- https://keepnote.cc/code/reactive-form-key-value-pair-bootstrap-angular-4-5-6-7

**StackBlitz link** : [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-key-value-pair?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Looks like the expected output got cut on the right. It would help to copy that JSON and paste it directly instead of adding an image for it

Comment: `{
  "details": [
    {
      "select1-inputvalue": "select2-inputvalue"
    },
    {
      "select1-inputvalue": "select2-inputvalue"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @Aneesh I have pasted the expected output json object here in the chat.

Comment: @NicholasK thanks this is the output I am expecting, Can I have look at the code it will be helpful if you could share editable link of the stack blitz project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following logic in order to *parse* the key-value pairs from the form.

.ts

```
public display;

viewJson() {
   this.display = Object.entries(this.keyValueForm.value.details).map((e) => {
     return {
       [e[1].key]: e[1].value,
     };
   });
}
```

.html

```
<button (click)="viewJson()">Click to see translated response</button>

<div>
  {{ display | json }}
</div>
```

[Forked stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-key-value-pair-egsg3v?file=src/app/app.component.ts)